# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear

I'm running a linear fit model using the `lme4` package in R and the following code keeps coming up with the error

> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Can someone please help?

```r
m1= lmer (elo ~  weight1 + bogirth1 + negirth1 + age + fight +
    (1|id) + (1|year) ,  data = datause)
```

The data is based on fallow deer fights and body condition during the rutting season.

Comment: What's your sample size? And how many levels for your grouping variables year and id? A singular fit might indicate that your random effects are too complex for your data to support. Bayesian models, e.g. with R package brms (which also uses lme4 syntax), can sometimes help with this, as they provide some regularisation to facilitate estimation

Comment: What did you learn when you typed `?isSingular` as suggested by the message?  The "Details" section of the resulting help page is helpful and clear.

Answer (score 7):

In this case it is likely that the variance component for either `id` or `year` is estimated at, or close to, zero. Without further details of your study and data it is difficult to be sure, but I would imagine that the culprit will be `year`. If you expect a `year` effect then you should include it as a fixed effect instead. If you have a small number of years, then this would be a further reason to exclude it as a grouping factor for random intercepts.

I note you also include `age` in your model, so there could be an issue with collinearity between age and year, so that is something else to bear in mind. You might want to investigate "age-period-cohort" analysis for further details on that.

Comment: @Shannon Does this answer your question ? If so then please consider marking it as a the accepted answer and (if you haven't already) upvoting it. If not, please could you let us know why so that it can be improved